# Accessing wireless from my Macbook?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

There's this network at my school which I *know* requires a username and password. If I access it on my PC, it asks for it, and I give it, and I get access. Works great.

On my Mac, when I select it from the drop down list of detected wireless networks, it asks me for *just a password.*  Like this is some normal home network. Which is wrong. Inapplicable. No.

How can I get it let me put in my username and password instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but, as this is working with tech, you never know:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Select Network.
3. Select "Wi-Fi" on the sidebar (AirPort if you're running SL or earlier).
4. Click "Advanced..." in the lower right.
5. On the Wi-Fi tab, click the plus sign beneath "Preferred Networks".
6. Enter the name of the network that you want to connect to.
7. In the security drop-down, select "Any (Enterprise)".
8. Log in with your username and password.
9. Press OK.